# How to find max of map reduce results in Couchbase

Tags: node.js, view, couchbase

Assuming I enter a document for each time a user visits with their name:

```
{
     name: "joe"
}

map: function(doc, meta) {
    emit(doc.name, 1)
}

reduce: _stats
```

My map reduce would produce something like:

```
{
  "sum": 214468085926,
  "count": 20732434,
  "min": 1,
  "max": 86257,
  "sumsqr": 10400744651756062
}
```

How would I find which user visited the most times?

A bad approach would be to group on username to get all the names, look up the visits for each user and find the max. There's gotta be a more efficient way to do this.

I have a huge data source so N1QL is WAY too slow

Comment: CREATE INDEX ix1 ON bucket(name); SELECT COUNT(1) AS visits, name  FROM bucket GROUP BY name WHERE name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY visits DESC LIMIT 1;  Checkout https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-index-grouping-aggregation-couchbase-n1ql-query/

Comment: With latest Couchbase Server, aggregate performance has been improved a lot, you might consider giving it a try.